# Google Apps: E-mails sent to user are also being sent to domain's secondary contact e-mail address

Tags: email, gmail, google-apps

I have two admin users on my newly created domain.

E-mails sent to one are also being sent to the e-mail address set in Domain Settings > General > Contact Information > Secondary E-mail Address. This does not happen to e-mails sent to the other user (the primary domain contact).

I have tried unchecking 'Inherit routes' for this user but it has not made a difference (I waited over five hours between unchecking it and trying again).

Any ideas what could be going on? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called Google Apps support and was able to resolve this.

It turns out the person who initially created the domain set up a "receiving routing rule" to automatically forward all e-mails for all users to his personal address.

Receiving routing rules can be adjusted via the Google Apps cPanel. Go to Settings, then Email Settings, then down to Receiving Routing, click Edit, and check your rules to ensure the 'Add more recipients' checkbox is unchecked (mine was checked and had the personal e-mail address set) or simply delete the rule if no other options are set.